# uninitialized constant YAML::ENGINE error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting this error `uninitialized constant YAML::ENGINE error` when i run `rake db:migrate` . I have the ruby version `ruby 1.9.3p327` and rails version `Rails 3.0.20`, my gems version is `1.8.25`. can anyone please help that whats wrong.

this is how my config/boot.rb file looks like

```
require 'yaml'
YAML::ENGINE.yamler= 'syck'
```

on this second line I am getting this error.

Comment: Have you recently upgraded your ruby version?

Comment: @BroiSatse No its like this was the first time i was trying this command, but i re-installed everything and it worked. I guess some files got corrupted while installing the last time

Comment: @dirtydexter Did you resolved the issue?